# Convert Tensorflow code to Keras

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN and recently came across Keras. I was trying to write my tensorflow code in keras but got confused. Here is my tensorflow code.

```
    #Input Data
tf_train_dataset = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,
                                      shape=(batch_size,  1, nfeatures, num_channels))
tf_train_labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, num_labels))

#Variables
 # layer 1
weights_l1 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([patch_size, patch_size, num_channels, depth], stddev=0.01),name="weights_l1")
biases_l1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([depth]),name="biases_l1")

#layer 2
weights_l2 = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([(block_sizeX * block_sizeY * 8), num_hidden], stddev=0.01),name="weights_l2")
biases_l2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_hidden]),name="biases_l2")

# output layer
weights = tf.Variable(
    tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, num_labels], stddev=0.01),name="weights")
biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([num_labels]),name="biases")

global_step = tf.Variable(0.0,name="globalStep") 
init_var = tf.initialize_all_variables() # operation init

#Model
 def setupNN(dSet, bDropout):
    input_l1 = tf.nn.conv2d(dSet, weights_l1, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding = 'SAME') 
    output_l1 = tf.nn.relu(input_l1 + biases_l1)

    shape = output_l1.get_shape().as_list()
    reshape = tf.reshape(output_l1, [shape[0], shape[1] * shape[2] * shape[3]])
    output_l3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshape, weights_l2) + biases_l2)
    return tf.matmul(output_l3, weights) + biases
```

Now when I convert this code into Keras I get confused as to what parameters do I put in for num_filter and (kernel_1, kernel_2) to match with tensorflow? These are just excerpts from the keras code that I wrote. Not the whole model.

```
#First layer
model.add(Convolution2D(num_filter, (kernel_1, kernel_2), input_shape = (1, nfeatures, 1), activation = 'relu'))
#Second Layer
model.add(Convolution2D(num_filter, (kernel_1, kernel_2), input_shape = (1, nfeatures, 1), activation = 'relu'))
```

When I add kernel_initializers=** does it take care of the weights on its own?

```
#Dense Layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu', kernel_initializer=initializers.random_normal(stddev=0.01), bias_initializer = 'zeros'))
```

I understand I can input the batch_size from fit() function

```
model.fit(train_dataset, train_labels, batch_size=100, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1,
           validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=3)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question,

`num_filter` is feature output space and (`kernel_1`, `kernel_2`) is the filter size/convolutional window. In your case, you can see that your TensorFlow code uses `tf.nn.conv2d`. If you look at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d), you can see that `filter` is the second argument which is in your case `weights_l1`. In terms of this `patch_size, patch_size` is equivalent to the kernel sizes and `depth`is to `num_filter`.

For the second question, if you add `kernel_initializers=**` this means that the weights or variables are initialised with values. The same concept applies to TensorFlow as your weights are a variable and this needs to be initialised with values at the beginning.

Comment: So the first layer reads:
`model.add(Convolution2D(depth, (patch_size, patch_size), input_shape = (1, nfeatures, 1), activation = 'relu'))`
I wasn't able to follow your answer on `kernel_initializers=**`. Is setting the weights in that way is correct? I thought Keras handles the dimensions of weights on its own. I do not need to do anything. Just specify whether values should be uniform/normal etc.. Is my understanding correct or do weights need explicit declaration like TF?

Comment: No it's more like this: `model.add(Convolution2D(depth, (patch_size, patch_size), strides = (2, 2), activation = 'relu', input_shape=(width, height, num_channels)))`. Concerning the weights, it enough to do this but somehow you're also setting the dimension of the weights in Keras by defining the depth, patch_size etc. So it's the same concept but different way to write things. Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes It does. Got it. Thank you.